# Replace Row in sqlite if duplicate key is not primary key

Tags: android, sqlite, replace

I have a table like this:

```
uid -> primary key
dbid -> other key
data1 -> ...
data2 -> ...
```

Now when I enter data and the dbid is already there it should only update data1 and data2.

I tried it like this:

```
sqlstring = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tablename (dbid, data1, data2) 
VALUES(?,?,?)";
```

With this it only updates if the uid is the same. What should I do to update if the dbid is already there?

Thx

Comment: Did you try adding a unique key on dbid?

Comment: changes nothing :-(   edit:   made a mistake. This is the answer. I changed dbid to unique and now it updates accordingly. thanks a lot

Comment: Added a simple answer so that the question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSERT OR REPLACE` inserts unless a uniqueness constraint is violated in which case it updates the row.

Since you want dbid to be the unique item, just add a unique index to that field and you'll get the behaviour you're describing.